# How to access linux environment variables from maven pom?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I want to access linux environment variables from pom.xml

I have added `WAS_LOCAL_HOST='http://localhost:9081'` to

`~/.bashrc` and `~/.zsh/rc/env.rc`

Now I want to access it from maven's `pom.xml`. I have tried `${env.WAS_LOCAL_HOST}` and `${WAS_LOCAL_HOST}`, but my IntelliJ still marks it as `Cannot resolve symbol env.WAS_LOCAL_HOST`

How to properly access this variable from maven?

Comment: You should be aware of making your build depending on your environment which is by definition not reproducible.

Comment: The question why you need such environment depending things.

Comment: We use this to inject the Jenkins build number and svn revision (or git commit) into an artifacts MANIFEST.MF before it is uploaded into our nexus repository. Note that we also have this in a separate profile. We default the variables to DEVELOPMENT whenever they are built locally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the pom, refer the environment variable, say `MY_VALUE` as `${env.MY_VALUE}`. Check [this link](https://github.com/cko/predefined_maven_properties/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure this applies but you could give it a go.

When you add a variable to `~/.bashrc` you just add it as a variable you can use in your shell. If you want to use the variable system wide I'd try to put in `/etc/profile`.

On the other hand where to declare these system wide variables sometimes depends on the Linux distribution you use. `/etc/profile` is the place the go when you're for example using a Red Hat distribution but when you're using let's say Ubuntu the user guide recommends to declare them in `/etc/environment`. you should probably look it up for your distribution.

Also, after declaring them don't forget to log out and in again.

Comment: *"Also, after declaring them don't forget to log out and in again."* - or alternatively source the rc file using ". ~/.bashrc".

Comment: I knew there was something like that but couldn't remember what exactly. Thanks for adding this!