# hive-site.xml not found on classpath

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, jar, hive

while running giraph hiverunner i get following error regarding classpath related to hive-site.xml, i have already set hive-env.sh, and bash.bashrc, but error is still coming.. any help how to set classpath and resolve this error..?? any thing else i need to modify..??

i have already tried hivejdbc ex its executes without any error.. but while working hadoop with jars gives error..

will be great full for any help..

```
13/01/16 11:58:23 WARN conf.HiveConf: hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.HiveGiraphRunner.adjustConfigurationForHive(HiveGiraphRunner.java:212)
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.HiveGiraphRunner.run(HiveGiraphRunner.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.HiveGiraphRunner.main(HiveGiraphRunner.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set on Hadoops classpath as well? In `hadoop-env.sh` there is as line `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`. Uncomment it and add Hives `conf` and `lib` folder to it. That does it for me.

Comment: thanks that seriously worked.. but after that, got this warning..and some other erros too..is their something else that i missed..13/01/16 14:43:16 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-default.xml

Comment: `hive-default.xml` is indeed deprecated. The only reason I think it's still in the folder is the fact it lists all the configurable properties, no? The properties you want to use, you have to set in `hive-site.xml` as you did. You can remove `hive-default.xml` from the folder and that should remove the warning. On the other hand, it is just a warning. If he finds `hive-default.xml` in that folder, he also finds your `hive-site.xml`, no?

Comment: Also, I just noticed you use `.bashrc` to set your variables? Remember that this makes them available only in your shell. I answered something about that a few days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196951/how-to-access-linux-environment-variables-from-maven-pom/14197288#14197288.

Answer (score 0):

Add export HADOOP_CLASSPATH= $HIVE_HOME/conf:$HIVE_HOME/lib in bash_rc or bash_profile