# Hive-metastore error: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

after resolving errors related to [hive-site.xml not found on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353394/hive-site-xml-not-found-on-classpath) .. following error started to appear. don't know where i am going wrong.. any suggestion..?? should i change permission,(read in some blog) but /tmp is already 777..

```
13/01/16 15:01:11 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Ignoring hive-default.xml found on the CLASSPATH at /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-default.xml
13/01/16 15:01:16 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
13/01/16 15:01:17 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2256)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3980)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4783)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:166)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:142)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:542)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatUtils.getInputJobInfo(HCatUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.GiraphHCatInputFormat.setVertexInput(GiraphHCatInputFormat.java:81)
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.HiveGiraphRunner.run(HiveGiraphRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.giraph.io.hcatalog.HiveGiraphRunner.main(HiveGiraphRunner.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Unexpected exception caught.
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1186)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.<init>(RetryingRawStore.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.getProxy(RetryingRawStore.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:98)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:245)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:169)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:166)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4786)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3579)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2372)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2335)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2250)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:443)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:355)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:215)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:156)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.registerExtensionPoints(PluginManager.java:82)
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:156)
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.<init>(OMFContext.java:137)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseOMFContext(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.initialiseProperties(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:363)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:307)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:255)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:182)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Well, it starts with a NullPointerException so something is not there. Can you post some of your code?

Comment: yes actually code provided by giraph itself, i am running HiveGiraphRunner code can be checked here, https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/trunk/giraph-hcatalog/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/io/hcatalog/HiveGiraphRunner.java     i did some modification but that part will not affect main code with this i used HCatalogVertexInputformat and HCatalogVertexOutputformat code to these are also on site in HCatalog folder..

Comment: its a apache giraph maven project based on hadoop, for graph analysis and after download, i was able to build project successfully on my laptop, and even rest of examples works fine without any error, working with hive is been a real issue..!!