# Hive table created, however map task is failing with exception

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

I have created a tweets table in Hive(hive-0.10.0 on CDH 4.6), stuck with the below error when try to execute query

```
hive> select * from tweets where id='442990122795929600';
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201404071250_0010, Tracking URL = http://swapnil:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201404071250_0010
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201404071250_0010
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2014-04-08 00:45:24,755 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-04-08 00:46:25,892 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-04-08 00:47:06,691 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_201404071250_0010 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://swapnil:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201404071250_0010
Examining task ID: task_201404071250_0010_m_000002 (and more) from job job_201404071250_0010

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_201404071250_0010_m_000000

URL:
  http://swapnil:50030/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201404071250_0010&tipid=task_201404071250_0010_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I tried adding jar "hive-contrib-0.10.0-cdh4.6.0.jar" to classpath, but no luck.

Can anyone help with the issue ?

Comment: What kind of data you are dealing with ? Is it JSON/AVRO file or plain text file ?

Comment: I am dealing with JSON data of twitter

Comment: May be your data and schema is not matching.
Can you share your hive table schema and JSON data file ?
Also which JSON Serde you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

HIVE-SITE.XML was not being located in class path and hive was referring to hive-default.xml. Due to which, hive-metastore service was not running.

Modified the environment configuration files of hadoop and hive by referring to

[hive-site.xml not found on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353394/hive-site-xml-not-found-on-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for `hive.exec.max.created.files` variable in `HIVE` - when the number of files created by your `Map/Reducer` exceeds the `max` file of `100000`(default value) - it kills the job
Also check your hive.log to have more information about your issue.